# Running total of expenses issue in Python code

Tags: python

I am in my first coding class in college and having an issue with an assignment. Details of the assignment and my issue, as well as what I have so far, are below:

```
'''
    Author: Frankie Barrios
    Date: 10.2.17
    Purpose: Budget Analysis Program
    Design a program that asks the user to enter the amount
    that he or she has budgeted for a month. A loop should then prompt
    the user to enter each of their expenses for the month, and keep a
    running total. When the loop finishes, the program should display
    the amount that the user is over or under budget.
'''

#Main Module
expense = 0.0
budget = 0.0
difference = 0.0
expenseTotal = 0.0

total_expense = 0
keep_going = 'y'


#Input Module
budget = float(input("What is your budget for the month?"))
print("Please begin entering the amounts of each of your monthly expenses:")

while keep_going == 'y':
    expense = float(input("Monthly expense amount? $"))
#*Having an issue keeping the expense running total at the end of the program?*
    total_expense = total_expense + expense
    keep_going = input("Do you have any other expenses? (Enter y for yes.)")

#Calculations Module
if expense < budget:
    difference = budget - expense
    print("You were $", difference, " under budget.")

elif expense > budget:
    difference = expense - budget
    print("You were $", difference, " over budget.")

else:
    print("You were right on budget. Great Job!!!")


input("Press enter to exit.")
```

***Results I am getting:***

What is your budget for the month?1000

Please begin entering the amounts of each of your monthly expenses:

Monthly expense amount? $100

Do you have any other expenses? (Enter y for yes.)y

Monthly expense amount? $100

Do you have any other expenses? (Enter y for yes.)n

You were $ 900.0  under budget.

Press enter to exit.

Comment: `total_expense =` and `keep_going =` should be indented (so they belong to the `while` loop). Also, you have three different expense variables - `expense`, `total_expense`, and `expenseTotal`. Also, Python does not make you pre-declare variables.

Comment: Your final `#Calculations Module` should be using `total_expense`, not `expense`. But please fix the indentation in the code you posted so that it's the same as the code on your machine.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was an error while adding my question here but it was indented in the actual program and still having issue.

Comment: Got it! Thanks everybody! Was the final calculations suggestion you made PM 2Ring. Changed expense to total_expense and boom it's working!

Answer (score 0):

As you want to add all expenese so this line should be in while loop.
total_expense = total_expense + expense

Comment: I suspect that that line _is_ inside the `while` loop on the OP's machine, as is the following `keep_going = input` line, otherwise they wouldn't get the output they're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Your program will loop for `expense = float(input("Monthly expense amount? $"))` because you always have `keep_going` set to `y`

To keep the `total_expense` as a running total of the expenses, you need to include it in the `while` loop. You also need to keep the `keep_going = input("Do you have any other expenses? (Enter y for yes.)")` line in the while loop.

Something like this:

```

```
#Main Module
expense = 0.0
budget = 0.0
difference = 0.0
expenseTotal = 0.0

total_expense = 0
keep_going = 'y'


#Input Module
budget = float(input("What is your budget for the month?"))
print("Please begin entering the amounts of each of your monthly expenses:")

while keep_going == 'y':
    expense = float(input("Monthly expense amount? $"))
    total_expense = total_expense + expense
    keep_going = input("Do you have any other expenses? (Enter y for yes.)")

#Calculations Module
if total_expense < budget:
    difference = budget - total_expense
    print("You were $", difference, " under budget.")

elif total_expense > budget:
    difference = total_expense - budget
    print("You were $", difference, " over budget.")

else:
    print("You were right on budget. Great Job!!!")


input("Press enter to exit.")
```